# Route + GET Parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to write my own router but I'm getting kinda stuck on my htaccess.
The route stuff all works but I want to be able to parse GET variables into the url.
I kinda want to be able to make this work: site.com/view/?p=1 or site.com/?p=1.
My htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

So that's pretty much it. What should I do to be able to use GET variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `I want to be able to parse GET variables into the url`. What URLs you want to show to your users and what you want them to be internally?

Comment: Oh I would be able to do stuff like:
site.com/view/?p=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an existing query string to your `index.php` file, you need to add the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yeah this worked for the url site.com/view/?p=1. Thanks!
What should I do to also make it able for site.com/?p=1 ?

Comment: Please note that `QSA` is not really needed here and won't make any difference here since OP is not modifying query string in rewrite rule.

Comment: @jeroen Nope, it will get seen as a controller right there.

Comment: @TimondeGroot That's not really related to query string so you should probably post a new question.